# Where is the detail reference to the Date format that Elasticsearch uses?

Tags: elasticsearch, standards, date-format, querying

Does anybody know which date-format standard is *Elasticsearch* using?

I can use `tomorrow`in queries but that is not mentioned anywhere in the docs, so I guess it comes from some other broadly accepted standard/library that ES uses.

I found just:

- [Joda-Time](https://github.com/elastic/opensourcesoftware/blob/master/docs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch%202.3%20third%20party%20licenses.md)
- [kbn-datemath](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/master/packages/kbn-datemath)
- [Date Math expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-math-expressions.html) (but no further insight about specs)

Not sure which of the two should I refer to, when writing my date queries.

Can you link to the specs of the used format(s)?

Answer (score 0):

EpochMillis and strict_date_optional_time are the defaults.

Comment: That is what is written in the [DateType Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html); I already passed from there. I think ```strict_date_optional_time``` is a setting, not the name of a standard; or, if it is, can you link the specs? While EpochMillis (being *Milliseconds since Epoch*) for sure is not supporting ```tomorrow``` as an expression, right?

Comment: strict_date_optional_time is ES's name for the ISO format dateOptionalTimeParser over [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateOptionalTimeParser--). The whole "tomorrow-1d" or "today" are part of [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math).